# How is L1 regularization derived?

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization, ridge-regression

I understand the basic idea of regularization. I am very curious to know the derivations behind it so that I get the complete picture.

I though a good place to start learning about regularization is Linear regression. So I was going though this [paper](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~schmidtm/Documents/2005_Notes_Lasso.pdf) and I got stuck in between. I didn't understand how equation 4 was derived from 3 and 2.

I understand from Gradient Descent method that, you first calculate the first derivative of the loss function and try to go down the path of decreasing gradient and stop when you have found the minimum. But here I don't understand why is derivative of a loss function is divided by itself?

Can some one please help me with this?

1. derivative of (3) should be $2X^T(Xw-y)$
2. dividing it by (2) should be $2X^T(Xw-y) / \sum\limits_{i=1}^n(y_i-w_0 - \sum\limits_{j=1}^p x_{ij}w_j)^2$

firs of all I don't understand why is it done? what is the purpose of this step and also I don't see how that is simplified to (4).

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, but getting from (2) to (3) in the paper you linked is a *very* basic step in matrix algebra or OLS, so if you have problems with this, you have problems with fundamental statistics. Giving an answer that starts out at this fundamental level and gets to regularization is not a good fit to SE. I'd recommend that you look at some elementary statistics textbooks or MOOCs so you understand the matrix algebra better, then continue to regularization ([this textbook is good for the lasso](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/StatLearnSparsity/))...

Comment: ... If you have *specific* questions about the material - like how to get from (2) to (3) in that paper - please don't hesitate to ask them here. We can and will answer well-asked specific questions, whether fundamental or advanced.

Comment: @StephanKolassa i meant how (4) was derived from (2) and (3).  Look at this paper [link](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/06/24/gradient-descent-linear-regression/) it's very clearly explains the concept of Gradient Descent. also here [link](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~tqchen/pdf/BoostedTree.pdf) slide no 22 it's mentioned that using Taylor series approximation regularization function is simplified. I read about taylor series and then came back to the slides and more or less go an idea of the derivation.

Comment: @StephanKolassa you guys are the in-charge here you can do as you seem fit. but I wonder how can a explanation behind a mathematical derivation can be put on hold stating it's too broad. guess I will never understand the stringent rules of SO.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I just quoted that paper as an example. I was trying to say that I went though many pages/papers online and was unable to find a easy to understand answer. 
Please tell me how, derivative of (3) wrt w divided (2) = (4)? and more importantly why are they doing this?

Comment: The question as currently posed asks about "the derivations behind regularization", and this is simply too broad. The derivation of equation (4) in the paper is proposed as an *example*. This is different from a question that *explicitly* asks about a specific derivation, which [as I wrote](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210849/what-is-the-derivation-behind-l1-and-l2-regularization-linear-regression?noredirect=1#comment400528_210849) would *not* be too broad. Does this explain why your question was closed as "too broad"?

Comment: If you are still interested in this specific derivation, I suggest you either edit this question to clarify this, or even better, ask a new specific question. It would be good if you indicated what you tried and where specifically you are stuck.

Comment: edited the question @StephanKolassa

Comment: Thanks, it's much better now. I have upvoted the question and nominated it for reopening. If it *is* reopened, I'll try to take a stab at it.

Comment: I've re-opened the question to expedite an answer, but note that it also needs to be edited so that it makes sense without reference to an external link.

Comment: @Scortchi Yes, Sir. I edited the question again. But I am confused. what Stephan asked and you are asking are in complete contradiction. He says asking for a general derivation is "too broad" and suggested me to ask any specific question from the paper i linked. You seem to suggest exactly the opposite.

Comment: You misunderstood me. Questions should at least *make sense* without having to read something else (imagine the link rots). So you need to include equation (3) in your question as well as quoting from the paper or paraphrasing it to explain what equation (3) represents. (The point's moot now as @AaronVoelker has done just that in his answer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Equation (3) from the paper states:

$$RSS = \|Xw - y\|_2^2$$

This is the "residual sum of squared errors" that we want to minimize. Differentiating $RSS$ with respect to the parameter vector $w$ (sometimes called the "weights") gives:

$$u = 2X^T (Xw - y)$$

Note that $u$ is a vector where the $i^{th}$ element is the partial derivative of $RSS$ with respect to $w_i$. We differentiate with respect to $w$ because basic calculus tells us that the minimum will be obtained when the derivatives are all $0$.  Thus, setting $u = 0$ allows us to solve for the $w$ which minimizes the squared error.

Now your question mistakes "dividing by $2$" from the paper with "dividing by (2)". There is a big difference, because $2$ is a number while (2) is an equation. If we divide $u$ by $2$, then we get (4):

$$X^T (Xw - y)$$

We divide by $2$ simply because this makes the derivation slightly cleaner without changing the results (because $0 / 2 = 0$).

Comment: My bad. I thought it was equation (2). It should have occurred to me, but it didn't. thanks for clearing this up.